# How to type right to left in HTML?

Tags: javascript, input, right-to-left

Couldn't find anything that does this (have Googled already).

Using JavaScript or CSS or HTML, is there a cross browser way to facilitate typing right to left for Arabic languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look better.
Anyways, here's a working solution I have found:

```
<input type="text" class="rtlText">

.rtlText{ 
  direction:rtl;
  unicode-bidi:bidi-override; 
}
```

This not only makes the input go from right to left, but also makes the characters themselves be typed right to left.

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/o440xcun/

Comment: Thanks, your code worked. Please make changes in your post to attach this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/o440xcun/

Comment: @gurvinder372 added the fiddle

Answer (score 4):

Use [`direction: rtl;`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/direction) CSS property

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/72v7Lhqj/)

```css
textarea {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: text is still getting appended from left to right, it needs to type right to left. Thanks though.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Use `unicode-bidi:bidi-override;` too as suggested by RJ45's answer.

Comment: done that, it works, here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/o440xcun/

Answer (score 1):

Use `direction:RTL` for the RIGHT alignment

Write a JavaScript handler attached to the event: "onkeyup", which performs the shifting of the entered character to the LEFT (doing some text processing).